# get secret from aws in systemd service file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, service, systemd

I have a systemd service in ubuntu and I want to retrieve the secret in the envoirment section and not put it hardcoded like this:

```
Environment="PASSWORD=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id aws_pwds | jq -r '.SecretString | fromjson | .test_pwd'`"
```

the command work in the shell but the service failed to get it any suggestions why?
I also tried using $()